# Sending POST to a url formatted like a GET querystring

Tags: php, postman

I have to make a payment gateway integration, and in the documentation, there is this :

> 4.4 Example of PayBill URL:
>   POST /PayBill?Reference=&Amount=&MSISDN=&TransactionID=&ThirdPartyAccountRef=&WalletID=&StatusCode=&StatusDesc=

However that looks more like a GET call. The above is the url that will ba invoked by the Payment plateform. It will POST all these variables.
I tried to retrieve information with Postman, but i get an empty array. The support engineer at the payment platform doesn't answer my question.
Is it possible to make a POST request this way? how?

Comment: `<form method="POST" action= "/PayBill?Reference=&Amount=&MSISDN=&TransactionID=&ThirdPartyAccountRef=&WalletID=&StatusCode=&StatusDesc=">`

Comment: You can definitely have query string params in the URL when you do a POST. However, I would guess that you're suppose to POST those params instead. Try it.

Comment: a post request can have query string parameters

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it's not me that does the request,it's the payment platform, i don't know how it does the call,me(ecommerce website) I have to parse the POST values.

Comment: So, what does the actual request you get look like? Is that in the `php://input`-stream, `$_POST` or `$_GET`-arrays? You should also clarify that it your question. Everyone, including me, read it like it was you that needed to send these variables.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I think ksjohn answer is right, bad documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is from the documentation of a web service.

It's a common practice in that sort of document to describe every operation with a GET-type URL while precising if you must use GET or POST to transmit the parameters. You don't have to send the params with both GET and POST, it's just an easy way to show you what parameters you must send.

Build your HTTP request with these params sent by POST and it should work. Anyway, just try it and you'll soon know for sure.

Comment: It's indeed a copy paste from the documentation. I wish you are right,

Comment: I bellieve I made the same face you just did, the first time I faced that kind of doc. And I had the same reflex, as absurd as it seemed.

Comment: I finished the implementation of the payment in test environment,the support engineer helped the best he could but didn't bother about the quality of documentation

Comment: He might be accustomed to that kind of joke... :)